# python iteration using range, why does the passed function not run the amount of times specified?

Tags: python

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKzX8.png)

```
def do_n(func, n):
    for i in range(n)
        func
        print('why?')

def print_n(word)
    print(word)

do_n({print_n('hello')}, 5)

output 
hello
why?
why?
why?
why?
why?
```

I was expecting both `func` (that prints the passed string 'hello') and `"why"` to print 5 times.

My question is why does `func` only run once and then why is printed 5 times?

Comment: Your `do_n` function never calls the function passed to it. Plus, if it were to do that you would get an error about set not being callable.

Comment: You are not *calling* `func`. Voting to close as typo. Missing parentheses.

Comment: @trincot - Theres no missing parentheses because `func` isn't really a func (its a set)

Comment: That is a second problem. Clearly the asker wants it to be a function. Probably expecting this to be lambda syntax or something (instead of set).

Comment: Yes, `func` is `{None}`, a set.

Comment: My interpretation was the op expected `print_n` to be lazily executed

Comment: Welcome to SO. The code has many typos, it does not run, please edit. @Sayse answer seems good !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is only run once because you don't *call* it in the loop. A function is run only when it is called, so you should be doing this:

```
def do_n(func, n):
    for i in range(n):
        func() # <-------- Note the () to CALL the function
        print('why?')
```

This still doesn't fix your problem. In fact, now the code will refuse to run because the `func` you passed to your `do_n` is not callable!
To understand why your code behaves this way, you need to understand how a statement is evaluated in python (and many other programming languages)

`do_n({print_n('hello')}, 5)` calls the function `do_n`, with the argument `func` set to `{print_n('hello')}`, and the argument `n` set to `5`. The value of `{print_n('hello')}` is evaluated *before* it is assigned to the name `func` inside the scope of the function `do_n`.

To evaluate `{print_n('hello')}`, first the function `print_n` is called with the argument `word` set to the string `'hello'`. When the function is called, it prints the first line of your output: `hello`. The result returned by this function (which is `None` since the function doesn't return anything) is the sole element of the set defined by `{print_n('hello')}`, so `{print_n('hello')}` evaluates to a *set*, `{ None }`.

Your `do_n` function receives *this set* as `func`. But this is not what you want to do. You want to call the function *inside* your loop instead of calling it when you specify the argument. To do this, you need to pass the function `print_n` as the argument `func`, and also tell `do_n` what arguments to pass to `func` (aka `print_n` in this case). You can do this the way [Sayse shows in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77173846/843953)

---

Alternatively, you can create a [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) object that fixes the value of some arguments to the function:

```
from functools import partial

print_hello = partial(print_n, 'hello')
do_n(print_hello, 5)
```

Now, you get the output you desire:

```
hello
why?
hello
why?
hello
why?
hello
why?
hello
why?
```

---

Yet another alternative is to create a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) (instead of a `functools.partial`) that will take no arguments, and call `print_n` with the argument `'hello'`, and pass this lambda as `func`:

```
do_n(lambda: print_n('hello'), 5)
```

[Kelly Bundy suggested this approach in their comment to Sayse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77173809/python-iteration-using-range-why-does-the-passed-function-not-run-the-amount-of/77173923#comment136050161_77173846)

Note that since the only job of `print_n` is to pass its argument on to `print`, you could skip `print_n` entirely and apply any of the solutions you've received (in Sayse's answer and mine) directly to `print` instead of `print_n`

Comment: Thank you for your thourough response, this piece of code was constructed as a learning tool and i am most definetely learning loads!

Answer (score 3):

the function definition is `print_n` and you call it the second you include the brackets and its parameters and it is resolved to use its return value immediately, where you are passing it as a parameter to your other function (but never really use it). The closest fixed code you could use is to pass print n's value in seperately and then do the calling inside of the function..

```
def do_n(func, func_param, n):
    for i in range(n):
        func(func_param)
        print('why?')

def print_n(word):
    print(word)

do_n(print_n, 'hello', 5)
```

Comment: Almost there . . . And done.

Comment: Still doesn't work. And I think [this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3p6akpimk5MfnaaSV5iXrKORpWnEpAEFafpFCpkJmnkJRYl56qgZMGCwFVKihCecWFGXmlWiol2dU2qtrcnGBzAMLAY0szy9KgWqEqAILANWA7MtJzE1KSbSCK1bPSM3JyVfX1FEw1YQ4DupGmFsB) is closer.

Comment: @KellyBundy was going to post a comment suggesting a lambda as well

Comment: The `lambda` version should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @KellyBundy - The ops question revolves around their expectation that their function call would be ran inside of the other function, not resolved before hand. I'd edited it out of their question that they're new to python because its just noise but imo lambda wouldn't really help with their expectation that their function as is should be getting called within `do_n`

Comment: @Sayse: In my head, the OP thinks the addition of `{}` makes a lambda. Either way, your answer or a `lambda` still executes the function from within `do_n`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I'm referring to your *"The closest fixed code ..."*. I think mine is closer.

Comment: @quamrana Yes, reminds me of a block in Ruby (although apparently they can't be passed like that there, I tried and googled and can't make it work).

Comment: Thank you @sayse for the explination it is very helpfull